# What does the “- 97” mean in the following code?

Tags: java, string, search, linked-list, contains

What does the “- 97” mean in the following code?

```
if (dictionary[(int) word.charAt(0) -97 ].contains(word))
```

we created an array of 26 LinkedList to simulate a dictionary.
each list contains all words starting with “a”, “b”, “c”,  …. “z”.
the code was given by instructor.

Here is the attached note:

> To search a word in a specific MyLinkedList
>
> Assume that the word you want to search is in a String type variable called wordstr.
>
> ```
> dictionary [(int)wordstr.charAt(0) - 97].contains(wordstr) ;
> ```
>
> would allow you to jump to the correct linked list, and the contains will return true/false depending if the word is in the list or not.

I just don’t understand why the “-97”

Answer (score 9, accepted):

97 is the numeric value of the character 'a', so if you subtract 97 from a character between 'a' and 'z', you are mapping that character to an index of your array between 0 and 25.

Comment: Thank you ... So, the expression    [(int)wordstr.charAt(0) – 97]    evaluates to the index of dictionary array?   And, if the wordstr is “apple”, then  [(int)wordstr.charAt(0) – 97] means (character at index 0 of wordstr  “apple”) ?  Ie, 97 - 97 = 0, which is the index.  Then “boy” is index = (98-97) = 1 ?

Comment: @greg Because of confusion you just had we call such numbers "magic" and generally [we should avoid them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). Instead of `(int) word.charAt(0) -97` part could be written as `(int)wordstr.charAt(0) - 'a'` which will probably be more readable (if you know that you can subtract characters to get integer representing their *distance* in Unicode Table).

Comment: Very insightful.  Thank you both.   And yes,    (int)wordstr.charAt(0) - 'a'    makes more sense.